# Update nvidia-driver on Google Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia, google-cloud-ml

I am attempting to train an AI model using Google Vertex AI.

I am using a custom container to and starting with specified `machineType` and `acceleratorType`.

My application requires nvidia-driver >455, but the machines come with 450.51.06.

Is there a way to update the nvidia driver version on the machine running my custom container?

Comment: This issue has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/203058431). We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the issue tracker and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: Did you resolve your issue via a workaround? I'm curious about a solution here.